# How does the value I give in the input remain after the web page is refreshed bu using vscode

Tags: html, input, refresh

I insert any data to input window at webpage, but after I refreshed page, the data where in input box is disappeared. I want this data will remain always unless ı changed by myself.

```
 <form>
        
       
        <div class="image float-l">
            <img src="hayvan-removebg-preview (1).png" alt="resim bulunamadı" width="170" height="150"> 
            
        </div>

        <div class="kutu0 float-l">
            <h2>Kesimi Yapılan Kurban</h2>
            
        </div>

        <div class="input float-l">
            
            <input type='text'>
            
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <hr>

    <div class="border">
```

Comment: don't use spaces in file names, if you tell the browser to refresh it clears the current DOM and recreates the DOM based on the new content on the file, the text you input was part of the deleted DOM

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your input from `<input type="text">` not to be rest when you refresh the webpage.
you could use id and local storage for that in JavaScript.

```
<form>
    <div class="image float-l">
        <img src="hayvan-removebg-preview (1).png" alt="resim bulunamadı" width="170" height="150">
    </div>
    <div class="kutu0 float-l">
        <h2>Kesimi Yapılan Kurban</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="input float-l">
        <input id="dataInput" type='text'>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="border">
        <!-- Rest of your form -->
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Add this <script> tag before the end of body tag eg. <script></script></body> -->

<script>
    // Get the input element
    const input = document.getElementById('dataInput');
    
    // Check if data exists in local storage
    if (localStorage.getItem('savedData')) {
        // Retrieve and set the data from local storage
        input.value = localStorage.getItem('savedData');
    }
    
    // Add an event listener to the input to save the data on change
    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('savedData', input.value);
    });
</script>
```